# How to plot zero-contour with tolerance specified in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am still learning Python/Matplotlib, so please bear with me.

I have a complicated function `foo(x,y)` with two input arguments `x` and `y`. I wish to plot the zero-contour of this function `foo`. I created a meshgrid in the required range using `numpy.meshgrid`, and tried plotting the zero-contour using the command `plt.contour(X,Y,Z,levels=[0])`. This returned me the warning: `No contour levels were found within the data range`. I think this is because the function is evaluated on a discrete set of values, where it is *precisely* **never** zero, hence no contour.

I therefore wish to specify a tolerance for this zero. Can anyone please suggest me a way? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends of course on your function, but it is *not* because of no grid Point evaluates exactly to Zero (in fact this would make this plot quite useless...)

The important property of your function and the space where you look at it is afaik: does your function really *cross* the requested level in your area of interest or is the level only *touched* between two datapoints?

Think of the function

```
f(x,y) = (x - .5)**2 * (y - .5)**2
```

It will be zero at x=.5 and y=.5. - but you'll get the same warning you reported above. Definitely with x = y = [-1, 0, 1], but even if 0.5 is included in the x and y vectors, the warning is still there - even if most of the solution is marked correct in the plot.

[image]

Look at the artfact at the crossing; this is due to the warning.

As soon as you really cross the requested Level, zero here, everything is ok, just try:

```
f(x,y) = (x - .5)**2 * (y - .5)**2 -1
```

[image]

No warning with this function, which really crosses zero within the viewed area, so this is a reliable result.

Comment: Thanks very much. that indeed seems to be the case. Unfortunately my function is known to only _touch_ 0 and not cross it. I need to see if I can still get a zero-level contour plot..

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is a different approach for you, did you already hear about `sympy`? It's the possibility to do symbolic math within Python (like with Mathematica or Maple).

After importing it

```
from sympy import *
```

You can define symbols and apply them to python variables

```
x, y = symbols('x y')
```

Then you can define expressions which describe functions of these symbols

```
f = (x - .5)**2 * (y - .5)**2
```

And the search for crossing/touching zero would be a nonlinear solver task

```
result = nonlinsolve([f], [x, y])

result
{(0.499999999999937, y), (0.500000000000057, y), (x, 0.499999999999937), (x, 0.500000000000057)}
```

It obviously still has it's computational rest error - but at least there is no big artifact area like with plt.contour(...).

And however, you looked for a solution, which returns some kind of tolerance and the result could be interpreted like this.

There is even a function, with which you can convert these results via numpy expressions to arrays of plotable data again, it's called `lambdify`.
However, this **should be used with caution**, as it uses `eval` internally, which can introduce arbitrary code if you don't know the source of the expression fed into it.

```
plt.figure()
numX = np.linspace(-1, 1, 1001)
numY = np.linspace(-1, 1, 1001)
for r in result:
    fx = lambdify(x, r[0], "numpy")
    fy = lambdify(y, r[1], "numpy")
    x_val = fx(numX)
    y_val = fy(numY)
    if np.shape(x_val) != np.shape(y_val):
        if len(np.shape(x_val)) < 1:
            x_val = np.ones(len(y_val)) * x_val
        else:
            y_val = np.ones(len(x_val)) * y_val
    plt.plot(x_val, y_val)
```

It's not too smooth, but it works and leads to this result, which is correct for my example function:
[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed answer. I'll try it out.